# What word has the highest numerical value in Tanach?

Tags: tanach, gematria-numerology

What is the word with the highest gematria (numerical value of the letters) in Tanach?  I'm guessing off the top of my head תשתרר of parshas Korach, but a methodical search might find something else.

Is there any source attributing any significance to the word that happens to have that highest gematria?

Comment: http://www.biblewheel.com//GR/GR_Database.php?SearchBy_Gematria=1500

Comment: @WAF that returns words with gematria of exactly 1500, not at least 1500, right?

Comment: What if it on a triple word score?

Comment: Torah Tidbits from the OU center in Eretz Yisrael confirms that it is the word of the largest gematriah in the Torah.

Comment: @sabbahillel Torah = chumash or Torah = Tanach?

Comment: @YEZ they said Torah and did not specify. see below answer for lists.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I did some calculations and came up with the top 5 for each sefer in Tanach, along with the top twenty overall. I also provided my list of top 10 for Torah and Tehillim for comparison with [AvnerMil's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40860/5151). For the Tanach source, i used [Mechon Mamre's niqqudless Tanach](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/dlx.htm).

The code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/Scimonster/4e47d57dd8d4b9875bae) on GitHub Gists. Comes with a README explaining how to run it.

---

Top 20 overall:

```
לארתחששתא | 1640
וארתחששתא | 1616
ארתחששתא  | 1610
תשתרר     | 1500
תסתתר     | 1460
ולעשתרות  | 1412
בשרשרות   | 1408
ושרשרת    | 1406
שרשרות    | 1406
שרשרת     | 1400
לארתחשסתא | 1400
לעשתרת    | 1400
והעשתרות  | 1387
העשתרתי   | 1385
ועשתרות   | 1382
העשתרות   | 1381
תשתכרין   | 1380
בעשתרות   | 1378
עשתרות    | 1376
ועשתרת    | 1376
```

As you can see, much of it is repeated, with מלא/חסר differences, or grammatical changes. Your תשתרר is number 4.

---

Now, for the top 5 in each sefer:

Top 5 in בראשית:

```
בעשתרת | 1372
תשוקתך | 1226
ותרשיש | 1216
תשוקתו | 1212
בשקתות | 1208
```

Top 5 in שמות:

```
שרשרת     | 1400
בתחתית    | 1220
תרשיש     | 1210
שרשת      | 1200
והשתחויתם | 1175
```

Top 5 in ויקרא:

```
שקערורת  | 1276
והתקדשתם | 1255
וקשקשת   | 1206
והתנשמת  | 1201
התנשמת   | 1195
```

Top 5 in במדבר:

```
תשתרר  | 1500
לתשעת  | 1200
תתנשאו | 1157
לשתות  | 1136
ותשת   | 1106
```

Top 5 in דברים:

```
ועשתרות | 1382
ועשתרת  | 1376
בעשתרת  | 1372
תתחתן   | 1258
תחתית   | 1218
```

Top 5 in יהושוע:

```
ועשתרות  | 1382
בעשתרות  | 1378
והתחתנתם | 1309
תחתיות   | 1224
לתשעת    | 1200
```

Top 5 in שופטים:

```
ולעשתרות | 1412
העשתרות  | 1381
תחתית    | 1218
ולהשתחות | 1155
לשתות    | 1136
```

Top 5 in שמואל:

```
והעשתרות | 1387
העשתרות  | 1381
תשתכרין  | 1380
עשתרות   | 1376
העשתרת   | 1375
```

Top 5 in מלכים:

```
שרשרות  | 1406
לעשתרת  | 1400
עשתרת   | 1370
ותשרתהו | 1317
תרשיש   | 1210
```

Top 5 in ישעיהו:

```
תסתתר    | 1460
שפתותיכם | 1256
תחתיות   | 1224
קשתתיו   | 1216
תרשישה   | 1215
```

Top 5 in ירמיהו:

```
תתערער | 1340
מתרשיש | 1250
קשתותם | 1246
נתפשת  | 1230
תפשתם  | 1220
```

Top 5 in יחזקאל:

```
מהתחתונות | 1315
מהתחתנות  | 1309
בקשקשתיך  | 1232
והתקדשתי  | 1225
תחתיות    | 1224
```

Top 5 in הושע:

```
תרגלתי | 1043
תורתי  | 1016
תורת   | 1006
רתת    | 1000
עשרתי  | 980
```

Top 5 in יואל:

```
ותימרות | 1062
ומתלעות | 952
משרתי   | 950
והתירוש | 927
תירוש   | 916
```

Top 5 in עמוס:

```
לשתות    | 1136
תשתו     | 1106
מעשרתיכם | 1080
לשלשת    | 1060
תתעלפנה  | 1035
```

Top 5 in עובדיה:

```
שתיתם  | 1150
נתתיך  | 880
פלשתים | 860
תחתיך  | 838
תשלחנה | 793
```

Top 5 in יונה:

```
תרשישה | 1215
תרשיש  | 1210
יתעשת  | 1180
שלשת   | 1030
נגרשתי | 963
```

Top 5 in מיכה:

```
התפלשתי | 1225
ונתשתי  | 1166
תשתחוה  | 1119
תשתה    | 1105
תחרשנה  | 963
```

Top 5 in נחום:

```
ישתקשקון | 1266
תכריתך   | 1050
מתפפת    | 1000
תשכרי    | 930
ומשפחות  | 840
```

Top 5 in חבקוק:

```
משמרתי | 990
לרשת   | 930
תחריש  | 918
ותהלתו | 847
תוכחתי | 844
```

Top 5 in צפניה:

```
התקוששו | 1117
תסתרו   | 1066
תרמית   | 1050
לשארית  | 941
והשארתי | 922
```

Top 5 in חגיי:

```
והרעשתי | 991
והמשתכר | 971
משתכר   | 960
התירוש  | 921
שארית   | 911
```

Top 5 in זכריה:

```
להשתחות | 1149
צנתרות  | 1146
תשאות   | 1107
תשתו    | 1106
ותפארת  | 1087
```

Top 5 in מלאכי:

```
ונשמרתם | 1036
תורת    | 1006
משמרתו  | 986
שמרתם   | 980
לתנות   | 886
```

Top 5 in דברי הימים:

```
בשרשרות | 1408
שרשרות  | 1406
ושרשרת  | 1406
העשתרתי | 1385
עשתרות  | 1376
```

Top 5 in תהילים:

```
תתפתל     | 1310
וקשתותם   | 1252
תמותת     | 1246
בשפתותיהם | 1243
תשפתני    | 1240
```

Top 5 in איוב:

```
והתעררתי | 1291
תחתית    | 1218
לעשתות   | 1206
תשתפך    | 1200
תשרש     | 1200
```

Top 5 in משלי:

```
מתרושש  | 1246
ותפשתי  | 1196
תתפש    | 1180
ונעתרות | 1132
תכתוש   | 1126
```

Top 5 in רות:

```
ולשתות | 1142
ותשתחו | 1120
ותשתהו | 1117
ושתית  | 1116
ותתר   | 1006
```

Top 5 in שיר השירים:

```
מתרפקת  | 1220
שפתותיך | 1216
תשוקתו  | 1212
בתרשיש  | 1212
שפתותיו | 1202
```

Top 5 in קוהלת:

```
ושפתות   | 1192
ולשתות   | 1142
וכמשמרות | 1012
תרתי     | 1010
תרשע     | 970
```

Top 5 in איכה:

```
תשתפכנה  | 1255
תחתיות   | 1224
לתשועת   | 1206
אשפתות   | 1187
בשחיתותם | 1166
```

Top 5 in אסתר:

```
תרשיש   | 1210
לשתות   | 1136
תשתו    | 1106
תפארת   | 1081
פרשנדתא | 1035
```

Top 5 in דנייאל:

```
כתרשיש  | 1230
תשתבק   | 1202
תנתש    | 1150
והשתכחת | 1139
השתכחת  | 1133
```

Top 5 in עזרא / נחמיה:

```
לארתחששתא | 1640
וארתחששתא | 1616
ארתחששתא  | 1610
לארתחשסתא | 1400
ארתחשסתא  | 1370
```

---

For comparison, the top ten in the Torah only:

```
תשתרר    | 1500
שרשרת    | 1400
ועשתרות  | 1382
ועשתרת   | 1376
בעשתרת   | 1372
שקערורת  | 1276
תתחתן    | 1258
והתקדשתם | 1255
תשוקתך   | 1226
בתחתית   | 1220
```

And the top 10 of Tehillim:

```
בשרשרות | 1408
שרשרות  | 1406
ושרשרת  | 1406
העשתרתי | 1385
עשתרות  | 1376
ותרשישה | 1221
ותרשיש  | 1216
וקשתות  | 1212
תרשיש   | 1210
ונתשתים | 1206
```

Comment: Oh man, Chabakuk needs to get its Gematria-act together! +1

Comment: @Scimonster: Mind if I change the final letters? E.g. בשפתותיכ   to בשפתותיך? (Or should that be "Mind if *i* change")

Comment: @DannySchoemann I'll update my script to fix the final letters soon.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Done.

Comment: Good way by using Mechon Mamre 's html files, that which i used also. However to count correctly, i assume that you had found the expected 304805 letters, 79977 words by switching exactly 9 letters in 9 words with their appropriate letters (1 aleph to 1 He, He to vav, etc.) without words in parenthesis.
Regards

Comment: How do you explain the differences between your list and the other answer's?

Answer (score 5):

I do not have the entire Tanach calculated, but as per the Torah and Tehillim, you are right :)
**Here are the top ten for in the Torah** 

תִשְׂתָּרֵר=1500
 
שַׁרְשְׁרֹת=1400
 
וְעַשְׁתְּרֹת=1376
 
בְּעַשְׁתְּרֹת=1372
 
שְׁקַעֲרוּרֹת=1276
 
תִתְחַתֵּן=1258
 
וְהִתְקַדִּשְׁתֶּם=1255
 
תְּשׁוּקָתֵךְ=1226
 
בְּתַחְתִּית=1220
 
תַּחְתִּית=1218

**Top ten in the Tehillim:** 

 
1310=תִּתְפַּתָּל
 
1252=וְקַשְּׁתוֹתָם
 
1246=תְּמוֹתֵת
 
1243=בְּשִׂפְתוֹתֵיהֶם
 
1240=תִּשְׁפְּתֵנִי
 
1236=עֶשְׁתֹּנֹתָיו
 
1226=בְּתַחְתִּיּוֹת
 
1226=לִתְשׁוּעָתְךָ
 
1226=בְּתַחְתִּיּוֹת
 
1224=תַּחְתִּיּוֹת

Comment: I didn't check your math (though I may;) ....where did you get this 'top ten' list from?